# Overloading a function template for a template <typename...> class

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, c++17, variadic-templates

I don't understand why this doesn't compile, can you give me a brief rationale?

```
template <typename... Args>
class Signal{};

template <template <typename... SignalArgs> class Signal, typename... Args>
void f(Signal<SignalArgs...>&& signal, Args&&... args)
{}
```

The error gcc provides is:

```
error: 'SignalArgs' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'Signal'?
   11 | void f(Signal<SignalArgs...>&& signal, Args&&... args)
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
      |               Signal
<source>:11:25: error: expected parameter pack before '...'
   11 | void f(Signal<SignalArgs...>&& signal, Args&&... args)
      |                         ^~~
<source>:11:28: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   11 | void f(Signal<SignalArgs...>&& signal, Args&&... args)
      |
```

And more importantly, what is a proper way to write such an overload? Do note that I need two variants of `f` - the one in question, and the other is `template <typename F> void f(F&&);` I definitely don't want any instances of `Signal`, including `Signal<>`, going into the generic overload.

Try it online on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Xawz6G

Comment: You don't have to declare `Signal` as a template parameter, just use two variadic template parameters.-

Comment: @Albjenow That is true. However that would also remove the ability to take a forward-reference to that argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `SignalArgs` does not declare a parameter of your function template. It's simply an identifier that may optionally occur in the [declarator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.decl) that declares your actual template parameter, which is `Signal`. It's basically the same thing as with names of function parameters in a declarator that declares a function type, e.g.:

```cpp
void f(void(*fp)(int a, int b))
{}
```

Here, `f` is a function that takes a parameter `fp` that is a pointer to a function that takes two parameters of type `int`. The identifiers `a` and `b` are redundant in the same way that `SignalArgs` is in your original example. They may appear, but they don't really serve any purpose.

Since `SignalArgs` is not a template parameter of your function template, there's no way it could be deduced (template argument deduction only concerns itself with deducing arguments for the parameters of a function template). The way to do what you want is to introduce a separate template parameter that is used in the type of your function parameter `signal` in such a way that it can be deduced:

```cpp
template <template <typename...> class Signal, typename... SignalArgs, typename... Args>
void f(Signal<SignalArgs...>&& signal, Args&&... args)
{}
```

working example [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Aclass+Signal%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctemplate+%3Ctypename...%3E+class+Signal,+typename...+SignalArgs,+typename...+Args%3E%0Avoid+f(Signal%3CSignalArgs...%3E%26%26+signal,+Args%26%26...+args)%0A%7B%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'0',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2+--std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:63.77358490566037,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:36.22641509433963,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: Thanks! I thought about this exact solution, but I wasn't sure if the compiler can reliably auto-deduce `SignalArgs` separately from `Args`. Good to know I at least was on the right track, maybe one day I can stop asking these kinds of questions and start answering them :)

Comment: The limitation of variadic templates refers to using them as parameter types. You couldn't for example do `f(SignalArgs&&..., Args&&...)`. But since you are unpacking the first as a type parameter, the compiler can deduce the concrete types from the way you call the function.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I expanded the explanation a bit. I hope it's now a bit more clear what the problem is exactly…